# Sharepoint 2013 Quick Launch

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have installed Sharepoint 2013 enterprise and setup some webparts and pages. But all of the sudden one of my quick launch links got a grey background?

Why does one of the link in my quick launch have a different background color than the rest of my links?

I understand that one of them is the mouse hover color but why is one grey, most visited or what?

I don't have any rep so i cant post my print screen... :(

Comment: Are you sure it's not the page that you're currently on?

Comment: Yea, its not the current site or current page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i have figured this one out. The quicklaunch link that had another bg color was the first link to a user created aspx page. It was the only page in My quicklaunch of that kind. All other linka where direkt links to apps or other sub sites. Creating another aspx file and placing that one over the previus strange colored link made the new aspx link in diffrent bg color.